# Failed to read dockerfile

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to dockerize my djangp app with postgres db and I'm having trouble, when run docker-compose, error is:

> failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount4260694681/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
> Project structure in screenshot:

[image: Project structure]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  gunter:
    restart: always
    build: .
    container_name: gunter
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
```

Then: `docker-compose run gunter`
What am I doing wrong?

I tried to change directories, but everything seems to be correct, I tried to change the location of the Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `docker-compose.yml`, you are trying to make a build from your app, from `.`. But the `Dockerfile` is not there, so docker-compose wouldn't be able to build anything.

You can pass the path of you `Dockerfile`:

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  gunter:
    restart: always
    build: ./gunter_site/
    container_name: gunter
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
```